# Changing initial value of a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, do-while

I am trying to add Books in my code. Let's say someone wants to add 30 books, the iteration goes from 0 to 30 which is fine. What if he wants to add 10 more books later, then it will simply do nothing useful, since I need them to start from 30 to 40. How can I fix this?

```
int currentBooks = 0;
do {
    System.out.print("How many books would you like to add? ");
    int nbBooks = sc.nextInt();
    // Add nbBooks amount to inventory array

    if (inventory.length-currentBooks >= nbBooks) {
        for (int w = 0; w < inventory.length; w++) {
            inventory[currentBooks] = new Book();
            currentBooks = w;
        }
        valid = true;
        break password;
    }   
    else {
        System.out.print("You can only add " + inventory.length + " books.\n");
        add = true;
    }
} while(add);
```

Comment: keep track of the currentBooks not just in a local variable but a field that keeps its value even after the method is finished. Or better yet: Don't use arrays but a List implementation as a data structure.

Comment: Also: don't use `break <label>`, its the "poor mans goto" and leads to unreadable and unmaintainable code.

Comment: I would use a list but we can't for this particular course and assignment, I don't understand how can i keep track of currentBooks?

Comment: How and where is `inventory` defined?

Comment: @Mohanad What do you need to do when inventory, you are putting into books is full and you have some books left to put into inventory? Do you want to move all remaining books to new inventory with the length of remaining books or to increase the size of an inventory you were adding books to before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disadvantage of a plain array (`Book[]` in your case) is that its length cannot be changed. **You should use a `List`** (despite the fact that you're not allowed to, for some strange reason).

#### With the `List` interface

Therefore, you are better off using the `List` interface (and an implementation of it, for instance, `ArrayList`), which uses an array internally, but it automatically extends its internal array if needed, so **you** don't have to worry about it:

```
// List is an interface, so we need a certain implementation of that interface
// to use. ArrayList is a good candidate:
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now we have created an `ArrayList` with the initial length of 0. The length can be obtained using the `size()` method, as opposed to an array's `length` property.

```
int nbBooks = sc.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < nbBooks; i++) {
    books.add(new Book());
}
```

#### Without the `List` interface

However, if you cannot or may not use the `List` interface, you have a few options, depending on what exacly you want.

One of the options is to create a class which holds your array with `Book`s, *and* a length as a property, because you have to store the length *somewhere*:

```
class BookList {

    private Book[] books = new Book[100]; // Or some maximum length
    private int size;

    public void add(Book book) {
        this.books[this.size] = book;
        this.size++;

        // You could optionally 'extend' the array with System.arraycopy
        // when the internal array exceeds 100, but I'll leave that to
        // you
    }
}
```

Note that this is virtually a kind of homebrew version of the `ArrayList` class.

In your case you have defined `inventory` somewhere. You'll need to introduce `inventorySize` or something, and each time you add a book, you also increment the `inventorySize` variable.

```
Book[] inventory;
int inventorySize;
```

and your method:

```
...
System.out.print("How many books would you like to add? ");
int nbBooks = sc.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i < nbBooks; i++) {
    this.inventory[this.inventorySize + i] = new Book();
}
this.inventorySize += nbBooks;
```

You can also check for the last non-null element (or the first null element) and consider that the length of the array, but that would be very bad code, because, for instance, you have to walk over the array to calculate its length, which might be pretty expensive in performance.

Comment: I cannot use array lists so I added a for loop that keeps track of the books created, but it doesn't work well.

Comment: for (int p = 0; p<inventory.length; p++) {
   if(inventory[p]!=null)
    currentBooks++;
   }